# Laravel Eloquent Join

Tags: php, join, laravel, eloquent

I'm fairly new with Laravel. I'm still trying to learn it. My question is:

I have 3 tables named

- games
- game_options
- game_platforms

  [image]

I have 3 Models for those tables

- Game Model

  ```
  class Game extends Eloquent
  {
      protected $table = 'games';

      public function platforms()
      {
          return $this->hasManyThrough('GamePlatform','GameOptions','id','game_id');
      }
  }
  ```
- GamePlatform Model

  ```
  class GamePlatform extends Eloquent
  {
      protected $table = 'game_platform';
  }
  ```
- GameOption Model

  ```
  class GameOptions extends Eloquent
  {
      protected $table = 'game_options';
  }
  ```

So when I do

```
$game = Game::find(1)->platforms;
```

It only shows,

```
{"id":1,"platform_id":20,"game_id":1}
{"id":1,"platform_id":21,"game_id":1}
{"id":1,"platform_id":22,"game_id":1}
{"id":1,"platform_id":23,"game_id":1}
{"id":1,"platform_id":24,"game_id":1}
```

But I need game name and platform names with those ID's. The thing is, I want to do this with eloquent only. I could go with "DB" or oldschool SQL but I want to learn if this way is possible or not.

Also I'm looking for better documentation/books for laravel. Most of what I read were only introduce laravel or far too advanced for me.

Comment: I might be way off base here, but I feel that you're using `hasManyThrough` when `belongsToMany` would fit here. I don't know much about `hasManyThrough` so you can certainly tell me if I'm wrong, but maybe try changing that. At least then calling `$game->platforms()` will give you a `Collection` of `GameOption`s not `GamePlatform`s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I left a comment earlier about this but now I'm pretty sure it's the answer you're looking for: you should use `belongsToMany` rather than `hasManyThrough`. So first, might I suggest you rename your tables and models to follow Laravel's conventions (plural snake_case table names, singular snake_case alphabetical order pivot table names, singular StudlyCaps model names), that way you'll have the following situation:

Tables:

- games

  - id
  - name
- game_option

  - id
  - game_id
  - option_id
- options

  - id
  - option
  - name

Now you can rewrite your models to conform to the new structure, and use a belongsToMany relationship too:

```
class Game extends Eloquent
{
    public function platforms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Option');
    }
}

class Option extends Eloquent
{
    public function platforms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game');
    }
}
```

Note: you don't have to model the pivot table (`game_option`) unless you store extra data on the pivot.

Now you should be good to get all options for a given game:

```
$options = Game::find(1)->options;
```

Or if you need to get all platforms (though I am trying to infer meaning of your code here regarding options and platforms):

```
$platforms = Game::find(1)->options()->whereOption('platform')->get();
```

Comment: As I mention above, I've kind of had to infer the meaning in your data, so do let me know if your platform/option stuff doesn't work the way I have assumed and I'll have a go at updating the examples.

Comment: great explaination of pivot tables!

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [with](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method with eloquent

```
$game = Game::where('id',1)->with('platforms')->get();
```

Should return you the game and platforms

For documentation I would first start with the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs) provided (find it to be about 50% complete) and with the [api](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/index.html) everything else is covered

Answer (score 1):

You would have to model your tables like:

```
**games**
id
name

**game_options**
id
game_id
name

**game_platform**
id
game_options_id
platform_id  /* which i assume you get from a platform master table */
```

Then in your Game Class:

```
class Game extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'games';

    public function platforms()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('GamePlatform','GameOptions','game_id','game_options_id');
    }
}
```

Now, this would be assuming that Game Platform belongs to Games through Game Options.